# Google Search Console Errors - Product Pages Using a Product Filter

Tags: seo, 404, error

OVERVIEW: I use a product filter on my WORDPRESS website so a user can search by make/model/year/transmission/drive/weight/etc...
(this is not a question for a plugin developer - this is a Google error/SEO related question)

I use a third party website to enter the product details such as - transmission, make, model, etc... Then that vehicle/product shows up on my website. All edits to a vehicle/product are done using the third party website, not my live website.

There are about 300 different products.

All product pages are given the /products/ path on the URL, such as: www.mywebsite.com/products/

So each product page looke like: www.mywebsite.com/products/2020-chevrolet-400s-2x2 www.mywebsite.com/products/2020-ford-300t-4x4 etc...

PROBLEM: Several product pages are coming up on Google Search Console as errors. Some come up as a "404" error, but the page is live. Other errors such as "Submitted URL has a crawl issue". Again the page is live.

I can use the Yoast plugin to prevent the /products/ folder from being indexed, but not sure that is a good idea.

Any suggestions?